# How to bundle and access javascripts in a bho dll?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, resourcebundle

I have a BHO (browser helper object) for data mining. A lot of low level DOM manipulation is delegated to javascript. Till now my application was picking it up from the application installation directory; but now because of some client requirement, I have to bundle the JS in the BHO dll itself.

Now my problem is that I haven't figured out how to add a JS file in my resource file (a.k.a rc file). I tried adding a HTML file (which is supported in visual studio 2008 IDE). But I fail to find html resource when I do something like this (`g_hInstance` is the `HINSTANCE` of my BHO):

```
    if(!g_hInstance)
    {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"Fail 0", L"", MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    HRSRC   hRsrc = FindResource( g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_JS), RT_HTML );
    if(!hRsrc)
    {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"no point", L"", MB_OK);
        return;
    }
    DWORD   dwFSz = SizeofResource( g_hInstance, hRsrc );
    HGLOBAL hHtml = LoadResource( g_hInstance, hRsrc );
    LPVOID  pHtml = LockResource( hHtml );
    HANDLE  hFHtm = CreateFile( L"c:\\temp\\Test1.htm", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL );
    DWORD dwWr;
    WriteFile( hFHtm, pHtml, dwFSz, &dwWr, NULL );
    CloseHandle( hFHtm );
    UnlockResource( hHtml );
    ShellExecute( NULL, L"open", L"c:\\temp\\Test1.htm", NULL, NULL, 0 );
```

**`My questions are:`**

1. Is it possible to add javascript in Visual C++ resource file (i.e. in any Dll)? If yes then how to add it and access it.
2. If html is allowed in a `.rc` file then why `FindResource( g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_JS), RT_HTML );` always gives me NULL?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. Steps followed:

1. Right click on your application's resource and click `Add Resource...`
2. Opens a nice looking dialog. There choose the `custom` resource button.
3. Provide a simple and intuitive name, like, `RT_MYSCRIPT`
4. It will open up an editor. Copy paste your script code there.
5. Build your solution and you are good to go.

**`Code to access your resource`**

```
void CTest::ReadResource()
{
    if (NULL != g_hInstance) // g_hInstance is HINSTANCE of my DLL
    {
        HRSRC hRes = FindResource(g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_SCRIPT), _T("RT_MYSCRIPT"));
        if (NULL != hRes)
        {
            HGLOBAL hgbl = LoadResource(g_hInstance, hRes);

            void *  pScript = LockResource(hgbl);
            UINT32  cbScript = SizeofResource(g_hInstance, hRes);

            if(pScript)
            {
                // Do something
            }

            // pScript now points to the contents of your your .script file
            // and cbScript is its size in bytes

        }else
        {
            ::MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed", L"", MB_OK);
        }

        /*
            Don't free the library until you are done. And do it only if you
            are loading the script from a resource dll or some other external 
            source !! Note: Also do a good amount of exception checking in your code!!
        */
        // FreeLibrary(hMod);
    }
}
```

**Note:**

My problem was including and accessing my javascript files from a DLL. Which I have resolved. The HTML issue is still there, but not related to my problem. I will update about it if I get a chance to use it in future.

Comment: How did you end up including the javascript file into the HTML?

Comment: @thefoyer: I was working on an `Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol` component. so I used to include my JS using something like `myproto://ui/jquery.js`. The application was written keeping `IE` in mind. So whenever I used to get something like `myproto://` in my html, the IE used to send it to my custom handler which I have registered with the windows.